# I need to write a simple AngularJS unit test for a controller that passes as defined

Tags: angularjs

Here is the controller and I just want to test that it is defined

```
'use strict';
 mainApp.controller('HeaderCtrl',
 function ($scope, sessionSrvc, eventSrvc, $state) {

    // Initially keep both SingIn and SignOut as hidden
    // until it's determined if the session is alive or not.
    var user = sessionSrvc.getCurrentUser();
    if(user.fullName != undefined) {
        $scope.signInVisible = false;
        $scope.signOutVisible = true;
    } else {
        user.then(function(user) {
            if(user != null) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.signInVisible = false;
                $scope.signOutVisible = true;
            } else {
                $scope.signInVisible = true;
                $scope.signOutVisible = false;
            }
        }, function(errorId) {
           // alert(errorId);
        });
    }

    /**
     * This callback is called when the the user successfully logs in
     * and the signIn dialog closes.
     */
    $scope.$on(eventSrvc.getSignInSucceededEvent(), function() {
        $scope.user = sessionSrvc.getCurrentUser();
        $scope.signInVisible = false;
        $scope.signOutVisible = true;
    });

    /**
     * Show the SignIn dialog.
     */
    $scope.signIn = function() {
        $('#signIn').modal('show');
    };

    /**
     * SignOut
     *
     * @param account
     */
    $scope.signOut = function() {

        var promise = sessionSrvc.signOut();

        promise.then(function(user) {
            $scope.signInVisible = true;
            $scope.signOutVisible = false;
            window.location.replace("/");
        }, function(reason) {
           // alert('Failed: ' + reason);
        });
    };


    /**
     * Detect if Cookies enabled
     */

    checkCookie();

    function checkCookie(){
        var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false
        if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){
            document.cookie="testcookie";
            cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false;
        }

        return (cookieEnabled) ? true:showCookieFail();
    }

    function showCookieFail(){
       // alert('Please enable cookies, the site will not work correctly without them');
    }

    /**
    * Set header back to portal header (from cookbook) if any tab is clicked
    */

    $('body').on('click', '.nav li a', function(){
        $('.header').removeClass('cookbook');
    });


    /**
     * links to cookbook or other docs
     *
     * If user clicks back button or clicks any tab, changes header back to
     * service portal (from cookbook).
     */

    $scope.goHome = function() {
        $('.header').removeClass('cookbook');
        $state.go('home.explore');
    };

    window.onpopstate = function() {
        $('.header').removeClass('cookbook');
    };

}
```

);

Here is the karma test I set up that passes :) Please bear with me as unit testing in Angular is new to me. How can I properly define in my test

```
'use strict'
describe('HeaderCtrl', function(){
    var scope, sessionSrvc, eventSrvc, state;
  beforeEach(module('mainApp'));


  it('should have a HeaderCtrl controller', function() {
    expect(mainApp.HeaderCtrl).toBe(undefined);
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers are instantiated on demand, when a view or a route needs one. So, your app doesn't have any instance of your controller, and your controller is not a singleton like services are. So your test doesn't make sense as is. What you can test though is the ability to create an instance of the controller:

```
describe('HeaderCtrl', function(){
    var $controller, $scope;
    beforeEach(module('mainApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _$controller_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should create a HeaderCtrl controller', function() {
        var controller = $controller('HeaderCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Makes sense - thanks. But my test still fails with a message: "undefined is not a function"

Comment: The stack trace would help. Where does it fail? Maybe that is caused by the controller itself. Add console.log() traces in the code.